# Preciso usar um middleware auth no controller se uso o Gates do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, segurança, authorization

É correto em termos de segurança retirar um middleware de autenticação de um controller se eu já defini um Gate no Laravel?

Fiz assim:

**No AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
Gate::define( 'admin', function ( $user ) {
    return $user->cargo_id == '3';
} );
```

**Na rota**

```
Route::middleware( 'can:admin' )->prefix( 'admin' )->group( function() {

    Route::get( '/', function() {

        return view( 'admin.home' );

    } );
```

**No controller eu tinha:**

```
public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware( 'auth' );

}
```

Quando o usuário acessar a página, ao invés de redirecionar para o login, retirando o middleware do controller retorna direto um erro de permissão. Eu prefiro assim, mas isto é correto em termos de segurança?

Answer (score 1):

Não faz sentido o que você quer fazer.

Uma coisa é o middleware `auth`, outra é o Gate. Um checa a autenticação, outro checa a permissão.

O middleware `auth` tem como finalidade permitir o acesso do usuário quando o usuário está autenticada. Caso não esteja autenticado, o Laravel retorna `401` para requisições JSON, ou redireciona para login, no caso de requisição web.

Já o Gate tem como finalidade definir o que pode ser acessado por determinado usuário ou não.
Um usuário autenticado pode ter acesso a um recurso, e o outro não. E é aqui que entra o papel do Gate!

Por exemplo, o usuário que tenha o `nivel_id` `1` pode ver o botão de cadastro, já o que tem o valor `2` não pode.

Nesse caso, você criaria um `Policy` ou através de `Gate::define` que tal usuário pode acessar esse botão. O retorno de um método ou callback do `Gate` deve retornar um booleano, para indicar se o usuário tem permissão ou não.

Comment: O que não faz sentido? Li a documentação do laravel, entendi o papel da autenticação e do Gate, quanto a isto aparentemente tudo ok. Minha dúvida é a que esta acima.

Comment: Não faz sentido querer usar o `Gate` sem o middleware de autenticação.

Comment: Desculpe a insistência, mas preciso saber, porque não faz sentido? No meu caso, sem o auth no controller, o usuário não autenticado, ao invés de ser redirecionado para a página de login, vê um 403. E o usuário autenticado que não tenha acesso também vê um 403. Aparentemente funcionou, minha dúvida é saber se isso é de algum modo errado em termos de segurança.

Comment: Por causa disto que eu estou perguntando — https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#guest-users. Onde ele diz "By default, all gates and policies automatically return false if the incoming HTTP request was not initiated by an authenticated user. "

Comment: @Flavio Você mesmo acabou de falar o motivo de estar errado sem querer. Quando o usuário não está autenticado, ele não pode ver `403`. O código certo para usuário não autenticado é `401`. O `403` deve ser usado para quando a pessoa está autenticada, porém não pode acessar o recurso. O `401` deve ser usado para identificar que não há autenticação. São duas coisas diferentes. Por isso eu disse que não faz sentido. Você precisaria entender esse ponto. Mesmo que a documentação diga que trata assim por padrão, o status de retorno vai ficar errado. É melhor ir pelo caminho certo do que pelo fácil.

Comment: Entendi o que você esta falando. Acrescentei o middleware a Rota, ficou assim — Route::middleware( [ 'auth', 'can:admin' ] ) — quando o usuário tentar acessar ele primeiro pede autenticação. Depois da autenticação, se o usuário não tiver acesso vê 403.

Comment: Exato, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu estava com essa dúvida, mas fui bater cabeça e ficou assim:

**Controller:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('can:admin');
}
```

Está verificando primeiro se ele está logado e depois sua permissão.